# Smarty dropdown not populated

Tags: php, smarty

I ave a smarty plugin that won't populate my dropdown box in my template.

This is my function_candidates.php code:

```
<?php

function smarty_function_candidates(array $parameters, Smarty_Internal_Template $smarty)
    {
$sql = "SELECT first_name, last_name, id, candidate FROM wmmw.main_members WHERE candidate='1'";   
    $result = mysql_query($sql)
              or die("Couldn't execute user query.");  
foreach ($result as $row){
$candidates[] = array(
"fname" => $row["first_name"],
"lname" => $row["last_name"],
"id" => $row["id"],
"candidate" => $row["candidate"]);
}
$smarty->assign("candidates", $candidates);
    }   
    ?>
```

and this is my template code:

```
<section>
{candidates}               
<label for="candidate">Candidate</label>
            <div>
                <select name="candidate" id="candidate">
                    <optgroup label="candidate">
                        {foreach item=c from=$candidates}
                            <option name="candidate" value="{$c.fname}">{$c.fname}</option>
                        {/foreach}
                    </optgroup>
                </select>
            </div>
        </section>
```

The dropdown box shows up, but no values are written in it.
What am I missing here? Any help appreciated...

Tx

Answer (score 0):

you can't just use a plain foreach loop with the return value from `mysql_query`. use a while loop with `mysql_fetch_assoc`

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$candidates[] = array(
"fname" => $row["first_name"],
"lname" => $row["last_name"],
"id" => $row["id"],
"candidate" => $row["candidate"]);
}
```